# Transposing columns to rows using UNPIVOT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that for some reason has hardcoded values like so:

```
Row ID    QtyC1   QtyC2  QtyC3   QtyC4  QtyN1   QtyN2  QtyN3   QtyN4  
100       10      5      8       9      11      12     5       6
101       9       11     12      5      6       10     4       9
```

The table has 35 columns and around 12k records (meaning around 500k values) and is being added to and amended constantly.

I am trying to transpose this in a view into:

```
Row ID  Year  Period  Val
100     C     1       10
100     C     2       5
100     C     3       8
100     C     4       9
100     N     1       11
100     N     2       12
100     N     3       5
100     N     4       6
```

So far I have managed to split it out into single values using this query:

```
SELECT Row ID, YP, Val

FROM (SELECT Row ID
    , QtyC1 AS C1
    , QtyC2 AS C2
    , QtyC3 AS C3
    , QtyC4 AS C4
    , QtyN1 AS N1
    , QtyN2 AS N2
    , QtyN3 AS N3
    , QtyN4 AS N4

FROM MyTable
) SUB
UNPIVOT (Val FOR YP IN (C1,C2,C3,C4,N1,N2,N3,N4)) AS PVT
```

This is getting me a single identifying value (eg `C1`) but how can I split it so I have a numeric period and a single character for the year (`1` and `C`)?

I can see it might be possible just splitting up the string into two parts but I was hoping for a cleaner way if possible.

Comment: are you trying to do this dynamically? or are you going to hard-code each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would this seem unclean?

```
SELECT Row ID, left(YP, 1) as year, cast(right(yp, 1) as int) as period, Val
FROM (SELECT Row ID
    , QtyC1 AS C1
    , QtyC2 AS C2
    , QtyC3 AS C3
    , QtyC4 AS C4
    , QtyN1 AS N1
    , QtyN2 AS N2
    , QtyN3 AS N3
    , QtyN4 AS N4
FROM MyTable
) SUB
UNPIVOT (Val FOR YP IN (C1,C2,C3,C4,N1,N2,N3,N4)) AS PVT
```

Comment: This is much simpler than what I was trying, I'll probably go ahead with this!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily split the `YP` string using `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, `SUBSTRING()`, etc.  My suggestion would be how you are handling your `UNPIVOT`.  It looks like you have a lot of columns to `UNPIVOT` so my suggestion might be to implement dynamic SQL to perform this query.  You would do it this way:

```
declare @colsUnpivot varchar(max),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @cols  varchar(max)

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','
                             +quotename(replace(C.name, 'Qty', ''))
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
               C.name like 'Qty%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @cols = stuff((select ','
                      +quotename(C.name) + ' as ' + replace(C.name, 'Qty', '')
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
               C.name like 'Qty%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select rowid, 
          left(YP, 1) YP,
          cast(right(YP, len(YP) - 1) as int) period,
          Val
     from
     (
        select rowid, ' + @cols + '
        from yourtable
     ) x1
     unpivot
     (
        val for YP IN (' + @colsUnpivot + ')
     ) u'

exec(@query)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28365/23)

Comment: This looks very useful but I'd rather avoid dynamic sql if possible.

Comment: @bendataclear No problem, I just figured I would show you an dynamic version since you stated you had 35 columns.