# SELECT comma delimited values into a single column

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have

```
SELECT 1,2,3
```

The output will be

```
colA | colB | colC
1    | 2    | 3
```

Is there a way to output SELECT 1,2,3 into just a single column just like this

```
colA
1
2
3
```

Comment: `select 1 union select 2 union select 3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transposing columns to rows using UNPIVOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568779/transposing-columns-to-rows-using-unpivot)

Comment: @shree.pat18 preferably `union all` as a matter of strict correctness, but yeah, that.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use `values`:

```
select *
from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(val);
```